# Эффект сканера радара с использованием jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, css3

Я пытаюсь найти возможное решение, как создать эффект сканера радара, используя `jquery` и `css`.

По существу, полупрозрачный треугольник будет вращаться вокруг средней точки `div`.
 Это возможно с `jquery` или я должен прибегнуть к другим средствам?
 Я предпочитаю не использовать анимированные gif-файлы.

Перевод вопроса: [Radar scanner effect using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18353107/7394871) @AndroidDev

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353107/radar-scanner-effect-using-jquery/18365050#18365050

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(function() {

  var $rad = $('#rad'),
      $obj = $('.obj'),
      deg = 0,
      rad = $rad.width() / 2;

  $obj.each(function(){
    var pos = $(this).data(),
        getAtan = Math.atan2(pos.x-rad, pos.y-rad),
        getDeg = (-getAtan/(Math.PI/180) + 180) | 0;
    // Read/set positions and store degree
    $(this).css({left:pos.x, top:pos.y}).attr('data-atDeg', getDeg);
  });

  (function rotate() {      
    $rad.css({transform: 'rotate('+ deg +'deg)'}); // Radar rotation
    $('[data-atDeg='+deg+']').stop().fadeTo(0,1).fadeTo(1700,0.2); // Animate dot at deg

    deg = ++deg % 360;      // Increment and reset to 0 at 360
    setTimeout(rotate, 25); // LOOP
  })();

});
```

```css
#radar{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:321px; height:321px;
  background:#222 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY6Tl.png);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#rad{
  position:absolute;
  width:321px;
  height:321px; background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbgUD.png);
}
.obj{
  background:#cf5;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width:4px; height:4px; margin:-2px;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px rgba(100,255,0,0.5);
  opacity:0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="radar">
    <div id="rad"></div>
    <div class="obj" data-x="120" data-y="65"></div>
    <div class="obj" data-x="140" data-y="185"></div>
    <div class="obj" data-x="220" data-y="35"></div>
    <div class="obj" data-x="120" data-y="235"></div>
  </div>
```

**Основной ротационный контур:**

HTML:

```
<div id="radar">
    <div id="rad"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#radar{
  position:relative;
  width:321px;
  height:321px;
  background:#222 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY6Tl.png);
  border-radius:320px;
}
#rad{
  position:absolute;
  width:321px;
  height:321px; background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbgUD.png);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    var $rad = $('#rad'),
        d = 0;

    (function rotate() {    
        $rad.css({ transform: 'rotate('+ d +'deg)'}); // apply CSS3
        setTimeout(function() {
            ++d;         // next degree
            rotate();    // recall function
        }, 25);          // every 25ms
    })();                // 1st start

});
```

Перевод ответа: [Radar scanner effect using jquery @Roko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18365050/7394871)